# Expected value of an order statistic

Tags: probability

Suppose that $Y_1$ is the first order statistic from *n* i.i.d. $\operatorname{Unif}(\theta - \rho, \theta + \rho)$ random variables. What is $\operatorname{E}[Y_1]$?

The integral that I got for $\operatorname{E}[Y_1]$ is $$\operatorname{E}[Y_1] = \int_{\theta - \rho}^{\theta + \rho} y_1\frac{n}{(2\rho)^n}(\rho - y_1 + \theta)^{n-1}dy_1$$ which should evaluate to $\frac{-2\rho n}{n+1} + \rho + \theta$. However, the solution sheet I was given says otherwise. Who is wrong here?

Comment: You should have $(y_1-\theta+\rho)^{n-1}$ in your integrand.

Comment: Can you explain why? When I plug the pdf and cdf for a $\operatorname{Unif}(\theta - \rho, \theta + \rho)$ random variable into the formula for the pdf of $Y_1$, I still get $\rho - y_1 + \theta$.

Comment: It seems to me (from proof by symmetry) the solution should be $\theta - \rho + \frac{2 \rho}{n+1}$, which if my algebra is right, is equal to your stated solution.  What different solution did the solution sheet give?

Comment: The answer sheet gave $\frac{2n\rho}{n+1} + \rho + \theta$.

Comment: Haha, the answer sheet answer is $> \theta + \rho$?  Clearly a typo!  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

The changes are in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$.

If $U_1,U_2,\dots U_n$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed over $[\theta-\rho,\theta+\rho]$ then

$$V_i=\frac{U_i-\color{red}{(\theta-\rho)}}{2\rho}$$
are independent and uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. Notice that $$U_i=V_i2\rho+\color{red}{\theta-\rho}.$$[The pdf of the first order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) of the $V_i$s is

$$n(1-v)^{n-1}\ \text{ if } \ v\in[0,1].$$ 
The [mean of this distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) is$$\frac1{1+n}.$$

Because of the linearity of the expectation, the mean of the first order statistics of the  $U_i$s is 
$$\frac{2\rho}{1+n}+\theta\color{red}{-\rho}.$$

Comment: An excellent explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Probably typo?  You need to shift by $- \rho$ since the original interval starts at $\theta - \rho$.

Comment: The typo happens on the first line: $U_i - \theta$ is $U[-\rho, +\rho]$ and so $V_i$ as defined is $U[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Using the transformation formula for pdfs should yield $f(u) = \frac{1}{2\rho} * |2\rho| = \frac{1}{2\rho} * 2\rho$ since $\rho$ has to be positive. That's the pdf for a $\operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$ random variable. It looks right to me.

Comment: @antkam:  Yes, you are right, I have to edit my ans.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a neat symmetry-based solution to this problem.  Imagine a circle of circumference $c$ and you randomly pick $n+1$ points on the circumference.  Then you randomly pick one of the points and cut the circle open there and view it as a line segment, now with $n$ points on it.  Then the first order statistic of those $n$ points = distance $D$ from left-end to left-most point.  By symmetry in the original circle all the $n+1$ intervals are identically distributed, so by linearly of expectation $E[D] = \frac{c}{n+1}.$  Translate to your interval and you get $E[Y_1] = \theta - \rho + \frac{2 \rho}{n+1}$.

Comment: Could you use integration to show this? When I did the math, zoli's answer checked out.

Comment: See my comment above re: Zoli's typo on the first equation.